# post request using deleteOne method to delete an item from a mongodb database

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I'm taking a Nodejs course and I am following along.

I did write the same code as the instructor did and when I execute the code it gives me this error

> Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

The error occurred when I tried to delete an item from a MongoDB database using the deleteOne method here is the code:

```
app.post('/delete-item',function(res,req){
  db.collection('item').deleteOne({_id:new mongodb.ObjectId(req.body.id)},function(){
    res.send("success")
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error means your trying to access the `id` field on a undefined object meaning `req.body` dosent exist.

This is due to a minor syntax error you have, the order of your response and request is flipped.

Change `function(res,req)` into `function(req, res)`.

Comment: thank you it worked, but why does the order matter in this case